# sending automatic push notification from mysql to android mobile

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

I have a database that contains some data and i want to get notified automatically on my mobile app if any value in the database is changed without having to check the database every certain time,i have tried many methods and viewed several tutorials but it leads me no where,any help ??

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be possible with only database. You need to write down an RESTful API which your app needs to poll to look for changes.
Ideal way of doing it is using GSM to push notify your app when ever you change something in your app. This will again require PHP/ASP/NodeJS etc... There must be some way you are updating your database? This should go exactly there.